# how to handle code that never executes

Tags: c++, linux, loops, networking, infinite-loop

I have some code that looks like this and I'm unsure how to handle the part which will never get executed since a part of this code runs in infinite loop while waiting for connections and when I terminate the program, it exits from there only.

```
main(){

// do some stuff....

    while(1) {
        int newFD =
            accept(sockFD, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addr_size);
        if(newFD == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Error while Accepting on socket" << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        if(!fork()) {

            close(sockFD); // close child's sockfd - not needed here

            // lalala do stuff send message here                

            close(newFD);  // finally close its newFD - message sent, no use 
            return 0;
        }
        close(newFD);  // close parent's newFD - no use here
    }

    // now execution never reaches here
    close(sockFD);      // so how to handle this?
    freeaddrinfo(res);  // and this?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I let it as it is and I guess OS should take care of it?

Comment: For this case, I would like to hook in the termination signal and use that to cleanly exit the program. In general though, for code that is never executed, delete it. Let your version control keep track of the old dead code.

Comment: Is your question about how to handle closing the socket, or what to do with the code itself?

Comment: Maybe this is a bit simple, but can you just check for a really high number and close then?

Comment: Why not change your `return 0` to `continue` after closing `newFD`?

Comment: @Rob I don't understand, how would `continue` help here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can, and probably should add a exit handler if your code is to be used by other people or you yourself just want it cleaner. In your exit handler you can toggle a flag that makes the `while()` loop terminate. The following code will work 100% fine for this use case and is reliable and cross platform, but if you want to do more complicated things you should use proper thread safe OS specific functions or something like Boost or C++11

First declare two global variables, make them volatile so the compiler will always force us to read or write its actually memory value. If you we do not declare it volatile then it is possible the compiler can put its value in a register which will make this not work. With volatile set it will read the memory location on every loop and work correctly, even with multiple threads.

```
volatile bool bRunning=true;
volatile bool bFinished=false;
```

and instead of your `while(1) {}` loop, change it to this

```
while(bRunning)
{
    dostuff
}
bFinished=true;
```

In your exit handler simply set `bRunning=false;`

```
void ExitHandler()
{
    bRunning=false;
    while(bFinished==false) { Sleep(1); }
}
```

You didn't specify an operating system but it looks like you are Linux based, to set a handler on Linux you need this.

```
void ExitHandler(int s)
{
    bRunning=false;
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sigIntHandler;
    sigIntHandler.sa_handler = ExitHandler;
    sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
    sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);
    while(bRunning)
    {
        dostuff
    }
    ...error_handling...
}
```

And on Windows when you are a console app its the following.

```
BOOL WINAPI ConsoleHandler(DWORD CEvent)
{
    switch (CEvent)
    {
        case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
        case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
        case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
        case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
            bRunning = false;
            while (bFinished == false) Sleep(1);
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleHandler, TRUE);
    while(bRunning()
    {
        dostuff
    }
    ...error_handling...
}
```

Notice the need to test and wait for `bFinished` here. If you don't do this on Windows your app may not have enough time to shutdown as the exit handler is called by a separate OS specific thread. On Linux this is not necessary and you need to exit from your handler for your main thread to continue.

Another thing to note is by default Windows only gives you ~5 seconds to shut down before it terminates you. This is unfortunate in many cases and if more time is needed you will need to change the registry setting (bad idea) or implement a service which has better hooks into such things. For your simple case it will be fine.

Comment: `fork()` in MS Windows? I don't think so. ;)

Comment: Hehe. I just added the Windows code because it is relevant for others who may search for this same answer but be on Windows instead. Hopefully it is useful!

Comment: Don't `(PHANDLER_ROUTINE)ConsoleHandler` either, that's just asking for trouble. You shouldn't need a cast. Also, using volatile and hoping for the best isn't good either. Rather, use the `Interlocked*` family of functions. Lastly, isn't the control-C handler executed in the context of one of the existing threads? That would be fatal if you waited for exactly that thread to terminate then...

Comment: You are right about the cast! Thanks for spotting. On Windows it is a separate thread, if you return from the Handler your app will terminate. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685049(v=vs.85).aspx  "When a CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT signal is received, the control handler returns TRUE and the process terminates." I've tested this and it is this way at least from Windows Vista and up.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt in regards to volatile bool it is perfectly fine for this use case, 100% trouble free. But you can do it other ways if you want.

Comment: Introducing an extra-variable for control-flow? Bad idea all around.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea for exiting an app? Closure needs to happens and this is among the fastest ways to do it safely and timely without bloating your app. Do you have a more elegant solution?

Comment: `volatile` is not a tool for communication between threads. However, Microsoft's C compiler defines its (implementation-defined) meaning so that it can be used together with the `Interlocked*` family of functions for that purpose. That's not generally so and C++ itself actually has atomic types which should be used instead.

Comment: It actually is a tool for that in this case. You don't need to synchronize all data access with a mutex to have a reliable, working multithreaded app. This is just one example, of many. The use of interlocked anything here is completely unnecessary, none of those operations need to be atomic for this to work correctly, every time. Everyone is free to lock all data access behind a mutex if they don't want to educate themselves about the times they may not have to. Better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Just a bit more information. It is hard to ever see a time where this will stop working, even with a different memory model on different processors. The ability for threads to access a global memory state would have to be removed for this to stop working. The worst you can expect with all current processors is that due to caching it won't be read on a separate core for some nanoseconds, which is not a problem for this use case. As such it should be future proof unless global variables are no longer allowed, in which case 99% of C++ apps wouldn't even compile anyhow.

Comment: So, what guarantees do you think are necessary and what guarantees do you think `volatile` offers over those you have when not using `volatile`? My claim is that for reliable, multithreaded operations, `volatile` is neither necessary nor sufficient! If you don't believe it, see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv. Nearby: Using atomics doesn't imply using a mutex, so you're refuting a claim I never made!

Comment: volatile is simply there to stop bad compilers from optimizing something they shouldn't. A real problem that has existed in the past. A good compiler should see that you set it in another location and therefore it will always be read from memory. Modern compilers should all be fine for this. So it is only used to ensure a faulty compiler doesn't optimize it away. So on those compilers it is needed to make the guarantee that the memory location will be read from. Sorry if I misunderstood what you were trying to say.

Comment: Quote: "within a single thread of execution, volatile accesses cannot be reordered or optimized out. This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution". If you still think that the purpose of `volatile` was to work around broken compilers and you can't see that this clearly contradicts the documented intention, then I can't help you, I don't know how to make it any clearer.

Comment: What volatile SHOULD do has zero impact on the use case in my example. What broken compilers DO DO with it makes it usable on the widest range of compilers. The reality is if you use modern compiler you can get rid of it, but there is zero harm in having it there. I don't know what kind of weird point you want to make here. The code works, it works great and will continue working until C++ removes global variables. If you have a problem with volatile in my example remove it and it will work just as good, just make sure you test it in use (easy to test, if your app doesn't close its broken).

Answer (score 9):

For these things, the OS will take care of properly releasing the resources on shutdown. However, more generally, you still need to make sure that allocated resources don't pile up during program execution, even if they are reclaimed by the OS automatically, because such a resource leak will still influence behaviour and performance of your program.

Now, concerning the resources at hand, there's no reason not to treat them like all resources in C++. The accepted rule is to bind them to an object that will release them in their destructor, see also the RAII idiom. That way, even if at some later stage someone added a `break` statement the code would still behave correctly.

BTW: The more serious problem I see here is the lack of proper error handling in general.

Comment: could you comment on 'error handling' part? I would love to improve my code based on your suggestions since I've never done this kind of work before.

Comment: Simple example: `fork()`. If you look at the manpage, there are three different groups of values it returns, but you only make a distinction between two of them. If `fork()` fails, I'd just `throw std::runtime_error("fork() failed")` as default error handling concept, so the fault doesn't go unnoticed. This also applies to other functions here, just read the according documentation to find out how they signal errors. You can also post your code for review on codereview.stackexchange.com to get further suggestions.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt makes good points and I recommend RAII for error handling as much as possible. You may want to look into ASIO for networking instead of raw socket functions as it will be going into the C++17 standard and allows your app to be cross platform with no more effort on your part. Windows sockets and Linux sockets have some differences which make porting more trouble than it needs to be!

Comment: @RylerSturden thanks for your suggestion. I would've definitely used it if my uni course wouldn't have made it mandatory to do this low level way.

Comment: It is good to know the low level ways anyhow, that way you can truly appreciate good networking libraries. ;) You could wrap that code up into classes yourself, ie CSocket, and in the destructor gracefully handle closing the socket and whatever else you need to do. That way your own code is RAII. I think all network c++ programmers at some point have written a CSocket type class. ;)